# Function setting up pointer on pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, assign

Why this work properly:

```
unsigned char* tab1;

int main()
{
   unsigned char* tab2;
   tab1 = new unsigned char[5];
   for(unsigned char i=0; i<5; i++){
       tab1[i] = i;
   }
   for(unsigned char x=0; x<5; x++){
       printf("%u\t",tab1[x]);
   }

   tab2 = tab1;

   for(unsigned char y=0; y<5; y++){
       printf("%u\t",tab2[y]);
   }
}
```

And this don't work:

```
unsigned char* tab1;

void fun(unsigned char* x){
    x = tab1;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned char* tab2;
   tab1 = new unsigned char[5];
   for(unsigned char i=0; i<5; i++){
       tab1[i] = i;
   }
   for(unsigned char x=0; x<5; x++){
       printf("%u\t",tab1[x]);
   }

   fun(tab2);

   for(unsigned char y=0; y<5; y++){
       printf("%u\t",tab2[y]);
   }
}
```

I can't assign pointer to pointer by function? If I can, how to do it? First version gave me 0 1 2 3 4, second 1 0 0 0 0, why?

Comment: Use `std::cout` instead of `printf` if sailing through c++ waters.

Comment: does it really matter? :o cout shows empty space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void fun(unsigned char* x)`

You are passing the pointer by value. When x is modified it is the local copy on the stack, not tab2. To do that you need to pass the pointer by reference like `void fun(unsigned char*& x)`

Comment: @pizzerman No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`fun(tab2)` is essentially a no-op since all that function is doing is changing the value of the input parameter `x` that is passed by value: it does *not* change the value of `tab2` in the caller.

The fact that you are using `new` is a red herring. Don't forget to call `delete[]` on the pointer returned back by `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
void fun(unsigned char* x){
    x = tab1;
}
```

and its call

```
unsigned char* tab2;
//...
fun(tab2);
```

can be imagined the following way

```
void fun( /* unsigned char* x */ ){
    unsigned char *inx = tab2;
    inx = tab1;
}
```

That is at first the local variable `inx` gets the value of the pointer `tab2` and then its value is overwritten by the value of the pointer `tab1`. Neither `tab2` nor `tab1` themselves were changed. `tab2` had indeterminate value before the function call and it has the same value after the function call. It is the local variable `inx` that was changed.

Function parameters are function local variables. They get copies of values of corresponding arguments.

If you want to change an original object in a function you should pass it to the function by reference and correspondingly the parameter must be declared as having type as pointer to the type of the argument.

That is you could define the function the following way

```
void fun(unsigned char ** x){
    *x = tab1;
}
```

and call it like

```
fun( &tab2 );
```

or the following way

```
void fun(unsigned char * &x){
    x = tab1;
}
```

and call it like

```
fun( tab2 );
```

In this case the value of the original pointer `tab2` would be changed.